# iOS 8.0 Simulator opens connects via HTTPS but not HTTP

Tags: ios, http, https, ios-simulator, xcode6

To replicate

1. Run Safari in simulator.
2. open https:/www.google.com with Safari - this works
3. open http://www.google.com with Safari - this doesn't work.

Only HTTPS calls are working. Any ideas why this may be?

Running iOS Simulator Version 8.0 (550.1), with Xcode 6.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working for me.

There is one issue with connectivity in the sim.  If you have the sim running while you change network configurations (move from airport to ethernet, change wireless networks, etc), then the iOS 8 simulator will think you are no longer connected to the network.  Is this potentially the issue you are seeing?  Try just rebooting the simulated device.